# How do I convert published Google Docs to exportable PDFs?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, export, pdf

I have a database containing the URLs to several thousand published Google Doc URLs.

These URLs look like this and are rendered as an HTML page:​`https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/<long-unique-id>/pub`

[Example](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vR0-T43mpVRlFYmAxMe55QrVEhbwR8hN6gmxhRHs9jn9dO7_-BuQjvBgLUUS5ZEZo2ol-nP_R9ez0zC/pub)

​​The formatting of these published docs gets messed up when trying to print the HTML page, ​so I need them to be PDFs -- either in a new tab or downloadable to the file system.

I've tried this PDF URL structure: ​`https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://docs.google.com/document/d/<another-long-unique-id>/export?format=pdf`

[Example](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://docs.google.com/document/d/1C9b-KlPenRRZ7wX4i7UwLf3BzJbC4GOIp_bBPERPsO8/export?format=pdf)

...But the ID from the pub version doesn't work with the export version. It would appear that they expect different IDs.

Is there any way to get my existing "/pub" URLs to work as exportable URLs? Or is there a way to reverse engineer pub URLs back to the regular, shareable URLs?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Are you able to identify the owners / publishers of the URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is No.

##### Publishing a Document

- Publishing a document creates a separate embeddable HTML version of a doc.
- Anyone with the URL can view the published HTML document
- The published doc can be a one-time snapshot or can automatically republish when the source doc is changed
- Publishing (or not) has no bearing on the visibility settings of the original document (i.e. 'Private', 'Anyone with the link', 'Public on the web')
- Publishing (or not) has no bearing on 'Edit', 'View', and 'Commenting' privileges
- you cannot adapt the published doc's URL to view or edit the original document

##### Sharing a Doc Online

What you are describing must be done using the original document's sharing privileges.  In other words, in the sharing dialog under **"General Access"**, giving **"Viewer"** privileges to **"Anyone with the link"**.

Once the viewing permissions are set, then you can create the export as pdf format URLs using the source document's unique ID:

**Download Google Doc as PDF:**
 `https://docs.google.com/document/d/<file_ID/export?format=pdf`

**View Google Doc as PDF:**
`https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://docs.google.com/document/d/<file_ID/export?format=pdf`

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's what I figured. My team are the publishers, but I was hoping that we wouldn't need to go through all of our documents to get the new link and I could just write a script to convert the published URL.